# WORDPRESS get the parameter of parse_request

Tags: php, wordpress

Im trying to make a virtual url in WORDPRESS basically i search that linking url: "mydomain.com/plug_page?=hellow" the url retrives a html that say "parameter: hellow" simple. if i write "?=cat" page says "parameter: cat"

im not really sure how i get the parameter... im a little new in php y found this code in the web i really dont now if any better method or if im in the correct way...

i tryed with this: "echo "parameter: " . $wp->query_vars['my_para'];" but doesn work

thanks for your time.

```
add_action('init', 'action_init_redirect');
function action_init_redirect() {
  add_rewrite_rule('plug_page/?', 'index.php?my_para=plug_page', 'top');
 }

 add_filter('query_vars', 'filter_query_vars');

 function filter_query_vars($query_vars) {
  $query_vars[] = 'my_para';
  return $query_vars;
  }

 add_action('parse_request', 'action_parse_request');

 function action_parse_request(&$wp) {
  if (array_key_exists('my_para', $wp->query_vars)) {

    echo "parameter: " . $wp->query_vars['my_para'];

   exit;
   }
  }
```

Comment: Are you trying to rewrite url's for your website?

Comment: im not intended in rewrite, in only want to add a virtual url to show some statics in the future

Comment: fially! i do this and use "exit()" so the page dont will display anything
`
add_action( 'init', 'codeTestRober' );
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'TestCodeFunction' );
function codeTestRober() {add_rewrite_endpoint( 'Codigos', EP_ROOT );}
function TestCodeFunction( $query ) {    
 if ( $query->is_main_query() AND get_query_var('Codigos')) {
  echo "Testing...";
  exit(); 
 }
}